# Create Appointment After Contact has been Saved

Tags: vba, outlook

I am writing a macro to create an appointment after a contact has been created.

A user can click the button, enter the details for the contact, and once saved, it should open a new appointment window.

The issue is the appointment sub being called before the contact has been saved. Thus, the object/contact does not exist to be passed to the sub.

My code:

```
' Application-level variables 
Public objOL As Outlook.Application 
Public objNS As Outlook.NameSpace

' Public Folders 
Public objPublicFolderRoot As Outlook.Folder 
Public objCompanyFolder As Outlook.Folder 
Public objContactFolder As Outlook.Folder 
Public objCalFolder As Outlook.Folder

' Set the Public Folders 
Set objPublicFolderRoot = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olPublicFoldersAllPublicFolders) Set objCompanyFolder = objPublicFolderRoot.Folders("Company_Shared") Set objContactFolder = objCompanyFolder.Folders("Contacts") Set objCalFolder = objCompanyFolder.Folders("Calendars")

Sub CreateEmptyContact()
    Dim objContact As Outlook.ContactItem
    Set objNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    ' Build out the contact item
    Set objContact = objContactFolder.Items.Add(olContactItem)

    With objContact
        .Display
    End With

    CreateAppointment(objContact)

    ' Reset vars
    Set objContact = Nothing
    Set objPublicFolderRoot = Nothing
    Set objCompanyFolder = Nothing
    Set objContactFolder = Nothing

End Sub

Public Sub CreateAppointment(objContact As Outlook.ContactItem)   
' Create the appointment on the public folder calendar with the passed contact Public Sub CreateAppointment(objContact As Outlook.ContactItem)
    Dim objCalAppt As Outlook.AppointmentItem
    Set objCalAppt = Application.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)  

    ' Add to the Appointment to the existing Calendar items
    Set objCalAppt = objCalFolder.Items.Add(olAppointmentItem)
    With objCalAppt
        .MeetingStatus = olNonMeeting 'Not an invitation
        .Start = Now
        .Duration = 120
        .Save
        .Display
    End With

    ' Reset vars
    Set objCalAppt = Nothing   
End Sub
```

What is my best method moving forward. For example, should I be using something like a WithEvents on the Contact_Send or Contact_AfterWrite?

Comment: Please use the `Option Explicit` statement in your code. You have two `Sub` but only one `End Sub`. That alone is bad. But, looks like your `.Display` method is *before* your `CreateAppointment` Sub. Switch out `.Display` to `.Save` and see what happens...

Comment: @JVBA The missing End Sub was a result of an error copying the code. As for the `.Display` and `.Save`, would switching to Save not automatically save the contact? This is not what I want as the user must type the desired contact information first. Also, what is the advantage of `Option Explicit` in my case? I already declare all variables.

Comment: Option Explicit can indicate typos in variable names as they are not declared. Consider Option Explicit to be mandatory. Microsoft is amiss in allowing it to be optional.

Answer (score 1):

You can either show the contact modally (`.Display(true)`), or you can watch the `Items.ItemAdd` event on the Contacts folder to fire (after the contact is saved) and use the item passed to your event handler.

Comment: What I want to do is show the modal, have the user input whatever information they desire,  then open a new appointment window with some information pre populated after they've saved the contact. I will look more into the items add. Is there a more appropriate event handler specific to the contact item I should be looking at such as Send or AfterWrite?

Comment: If you want to show the contact modally, all you have to do is replace Disptay with Display true.

Comment: My issue is not getting the modal to display, my issue is having the appointment sub not be called until the contactitem has been saved by the user hitting save on the modal window after entering any info/fields they wish. I think I am on the right track with using Item_Send event handler, but I am ironing out some more issues and can report back with findings.

Comment: I really do not understand - do you want CreateAppointment() to be called *before* the contact is saved?

Comment: No - I want the CreateAppointment() to only be called ONCE the contact is saved.

Comment: Then Items.ItemAdd event on the folder is the way to go.